# Show that $\frac{a^2+1}{b+c}+\frac{b^2+1}{a+c}+\frac{c^2+1}{a+b} \ge 3$

Tags: inequality

> If $a,b,c$ are positive numbers then show that 
>   $$\dfrac{a^2+1}{b+c}+\dfrac{b^2+1}{a+c}+\dfrac{c^2+1}{a+b} \ge 3$$

I am stuck at the first stage. Please give me some hints so that I can solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $a^2+1 \ge 2a$ and also use NESBIT Inequality.

Note that  $(a-1)^2\ge 0 \implies a^2+1 \ge 2a$

Otherwise use $AM \ge GM $ for $a^2$ and $1$, you get $a^2+1 \ge 2a$.

**NESBITT Inequality:** $$\dfrac{a}{b+c}+\dfrac{b}{a+c}+\dfrac{c}{a+b} \ge \dfrac 3 2$$

For proof of **NESBITT Inequality** you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 2):

Direct Question of [Titu's Lemma](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/blog.php?b=25220).

$\dfrac{1}{b+c}+ \dfrac{1}{c+a}+\dfrac{1}{a+b} \ge \dfrac{(1+1+1)^2}{2(a+b+c)}$

Similarly,

$\dfrac{a^2}{b+c}+ \dfrac{b^2}{c+a}+\dfrac{c^2}{a+b} \ge \dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{2(a+b+c)}$

Let, $a+b+c=k$

$\dfrac{3^2}{2k}+\dfrac{k}{2} \ge 2\sqrt{3^2 \cdot \dfrac{k}{2} \dfrac{1}{2k}} = 3$, we are done.

Comment: I think $\frac{a^2}{b+c}+ \frac{b^2}{c+a}+\frac{c^2}{a+b} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2(a+b+c)}$. You forgot about $2$.

Comment: @Argha: Exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $a=b=c=x$ and then using $ x^2+1 \ge x $ gives the required result.

This seems true for a lot of symmetric inequalities. I wonder if there is a Grand Theorem for Symmetric Inequalities?

Comment: It is to be justified why $a = b=c$ may be assumed without loss of generality.

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM and C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+1}{b+c}\geq3\sqrt[3]{\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a^2+1)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}}=3\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{\prod\limits_{cyc}\left((a^2+1)(1+b^2)\right)}}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}}\geq$$
$$\geq3\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{\prod\limits_{cyc}\left(a+b\right)^2}}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}}=3$$